# React Native metro bundler's running issue

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

I am developing mobile app using React-native-cli.
But I have got one difficult problem to solve.
I don't know why this issue is appeared.
I want RN experts to help me to solve this problem.
This issue is following.
I tried to run my app using following command.
react-native run-android -- --reset-cache
When my internet speed is very fast, my app is running well, but when internet speed is some slowly, it is not running.
My project is based on RN 0.59.

issue:
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `scheduler/tracing` from `\working\temp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js`: Module `scheduler/tracing` does not exist in the Haste module map

please help me!!! :)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gL1jl.png)

Comment: Please post your error messages, [not pictures of your screen](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/).

Comment: There is thread about this issue on [github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21150)